# Flask app works fine locally but not on heroku

Tags: flask, heroku

I have this flask app running just fine locally, but when I deploy to heroku i'm getting error 404.

This is my *init*_.py file:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

This is how i'm defining my routes in the routes.py:

```
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

@routes.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

This is my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from app.routes.routes import routes

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = '<mysecretkey>'
app.register_blueprint(routes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

And this is my folder structure:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dowuF.png

When I deploy on heroku and then open the app i'm getting this error:

```
at=info method=GET path="/" host=app-decasa-f7d5377cff67.herokuapp.com request_id=a04276df-0bbf-4a0c-a927-e92feb5f0383 fwd="189.46.208.51" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=375 protocol=https
2024-01-22T00:52:10.131183+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.27.170 - - [22/Jan/2024:00:52:10 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 207 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/105.0.0.0"
```

What can I do? I've already tried some things like put all the routes in the app.py file, tried changing the way I refer the my routes in my templates, but nothing works on heroku.